# Catch and retry bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm running in to a situation where the curl seeks that I do to a server to fetch some information intermittently breaks and instead of populating the resultant file with actual information it populates it with error it got and then move to next datapoint(in for loop), so I decided to catch and retry.(Using bash). But for some reason it's not doing what it should be, the generated file turns out to be empty. Below is what I have written, if you have a better/easier way to approach this or see a problem in below please go ahead and share. Thanks in advance.

```
 for i in `cat master_db_list`
 do
 curl -sN --negotiate -u foo:bar "${URL}/$i/table" > $table_info/${i}
 #Seek error catch
 result=`cat $table_info/${i} | grep  -i "Error"`
 #lowercase comparison, since error can be in any case
 echo -e "result is: $result \n" >> $job_log 2>&1
 while [[ "${result,,}" =~ error ]]
 do
 echo "Retrying table list generation for ${i}" >> $job_log 2>&1
 curl -sN --negotiate -u foo:bar "${URL}/$i/table" > $table_info/${i}
 result=`cat $table_info/${i} | grep  -i "Error"`
 done
 done
```

Answer (score 0):

turns out , nothing wrong with above, some of the curls calls returned empty values, decreased seek frequency with sleeps in between and is working all ok now.